# Como fazer um retângulo de asteriscos usando for?

Tags: java, loop

Para resolver este exercício:

> Escreva um programa que imprima um retângulo de n x m asteriscos, no
>   qual os valores de n e m são fornecidos pelo usuário. Por exemplo,
>   para valores de n = 5 e m = 7, o resultado esperado é:
>
> *******-
>   *******-
>   *******-
>   *******-
>   *******-

Fiz este código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class RetanguloAsteriscos
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     int m, n;

`Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
 n = teclado.nextInt();
 m = teclado.nextInt();

 for (int i=1 ; i <= n ; i++)
 {
     System.out.println("*");
 }
 for (int j=1 ; j <= m ; j++)
 {
     System.out.print("*");
 }`

Acontece que eu não obtive o resultado esperado, usando os mesmos valores do exemplo, o retângulo do meu programa sai assim:

> *-
>   *-
>   *-
>   *-
>   *-
>   *******-

Como resolver isso?

Comment: A regra é um for para repetir as linhas e um interno concatenando cada asterisco com a mesma quantidade do for

Comment: Existe alguma restrição ao uso da biblioteca padrão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somente com laço, pode fazer dessa forma:

```
int linhas = 4;
int colunas = 7;

for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}

System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < linhas - 2; i++) {

    System.out.print("*");

    for (int j = 0; j < colunas - 2; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println("*");
}

for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}

System.out.println();
```

Resultado com colunas = 7 e linhas = 4:

```
*******
*******
*******
*******
```

Funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/OwdYjk

---

**Referência:**

[Printing a Square with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238188/5524514)

Answer (score 2):

Com `for` você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
int colunas = 7, linhas = 4;

for(int l = 0; l < linhas; l++){
    for(int c = 0; c < colunas; c++){
        System.out.print("*"); // colunas
    }
    System.out.println(); // linhas
}
```

output:

```
*******
*******
*******
*******
```

[<kbd>Exemplo Ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/KuLYF5)

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = teclado.nextInt();
int m = teclado.nextInt();
int temp = m;
for( ; n > 0 ; n-- ){
   for( temp = m; temp > 0 ; temp-- ){
      System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```